# Interpreting circular doubly linked list implementation which uses union

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am having some trouble interpreting this doubly-linked list:

```
struct _dnode {
    union {
        struct _dnode *head;
        struct _dnode *next;
    };
    union {
        struct _dnode *tail;
        struct _dnode *prev;
    };
};

typedef struct _dnode sys_dlist_t;
typedef struct _dnode sys_dnode_t;
```

And further functions are defined on this list, like, for example finding if given node is head of the list:

```
static inline int sys_dlist_is_head(sys_dlist_t *list, sys_dnode_t *node)
{
    return list->head == node;
}
```

Now, my questions are -

(i) Why would we need a union here? That too, in this specific way?

(ii) How come both the `list` and `node` of the list are going to be pointers of same type? (see `typedef` declaration)

(iii) If I declare a list of such a type, ie. the `data_node` items will be the elements of the `sys_dlist_t` type:

```
struct data_node{
    sys_dnode_t node;
    int data = 0;
} data_node[2];
```

and I declare a node such that:

```
sys_dnode_t *node = NULL;
```

and then if I want to iterate over my list to check if the `data` of the `data_node` element matches say, a number 3. Can I do that by typecasting `node` (which is currently a pointer to type `sys_dnode_t`) to a pointer to type `data_node`?

Now, in the code, this has been done, and it is like:

```
if (((struct data_node *)node)->data == 3) {
    break;
}
```

This bewilders me. I may have missed some code to figure this out, so please tell me if you need more information. Can we typecast a `node` pointer to point to some struct that contains `node` and then access other data of the struct? How does this work?

**EDIT 1:**
Few more info on this list:

*"The lists are expected to be initialized such that both the head and tail pointers point to the list itself. Initializing the lists in such a fashion simplifies the adding and removing of nodes to/from the list."*

The initialization is as follows:

```
static inline void sys_dlist_init(sys_dlist_t *list)
{
    list->head = (sys_dnode_t *)list;
    list->tail = (sys_dnode_t *)list;
}
```

Comment: For case `iii`, the `data_node` structure is a way to emulate inheritance in C.

Comment: Are you sure that in `sys_dlist_is_head` should be comparison with `tail`?

Comment: @freestyle oh you're right. let me correct that

Comment: In a circular doubly-linked list, it's so convenient to do, since you can look at the list structure as a pseudo node. But from your description, I do not understand if this list is circular. Can you show list initialization?

Comment: @freestyle I have added the initialization part, correct me if I am wrong, but it does look like a circular dll

Comment: Yes, it should be circular.

Comment: `i`: there is a subtle difference from "reuse" and "misuse". In the 80's the idea of "reuse" was "write as less code as possible". However "a list is not a node", but "a list contains nodes" or "a list contains the references to head and tail nodes", so in modern list implementations, the concepts (classes/structs) of list and nodes are usually kept separated, with more code written but no "discouraged" code written (read: type casting). The fact that node and list have the same "shape" (two pointers to nodes) is not sufficient to let the two types collapse into one, today, usually, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (i) Why would we need a union here? That too, in this specific way?

So convenient, since this list is cyclic. The list structure is a pseudo node in the list. Therefore, the node can be viewed as a list structure and as node in a list.

Another definition might be:

```
union _dnode {
    struct {
        union _dnode *head;
        union _dnode *tail;
    };
    struct {
        union _dnode *next;
        union _dnode *prev;
    };
};

typedef union _dnode sys_dlist_t;
typedef union _dnode sys_dnode_t;
```

> (ii) How come both the list and node of the list are going to be pointers of same type? (see typedef declaration)

This is also convenient to do, since these pointers refer to the same structure in memory.

> (iii) If I declare a list of such a type, ie. the data_node items will be the elements of the sys_dlist_t type... Can I do that by typecasting node (which is currently a pointer to type sys_dnode_t) to a pointer to type data_node?

You can, because the pointer to the first field in the structure and the pointer to the structure are the same.

A node field need not be the first, but then a simple typecasting can not do that. For example:

```
struct list_elem {
    int foo;
    char *bar;
    ...
    sys_dnode_t siblings;
};

sys_dnode_t *node;
struct list_elem *elem;

elem = (struct list_elem *)((char *)node - offsetof(struct list_elem, siblings));
```

or if you define macro:

```
#define objectof(_ObjectT,_Field,x) \
    ((_ObjectT *)((char *)(x) - offsetof(_ObjectT,_Field)))

elem = objectof(struct list_elem, siblings, node);
```

Comment: wow, thank you for this detailed explanation, it is clear to me now. So if it is not the first field, then I would need to use `offsetof` while typecasting it, right?

Comment: Yes. More over. If it the first filed then `offsetof` will work too, because `offsetof` will be 0.