# Interpreting the loop condition of custom circular doubly linked list

Tags: c, list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I have a list inside a structure,

```
struct A{
    list B;
};
```

I also have a pointer to this structure like

```
struct A *a;
```

Now, assume the list is already implemented, and its elements are of type `elem`.

Then, I do the following -

(i) I get the head of the list in `nodeL` (a pointer of `elem` type)

```
elem * nodeL = list_get_head(&(a->B));
```

(ii) I now loop through the list in this way:

```
while(nodeL != (elem *)(&a->B)){ // did not get this part ----- I
    ; //some code here
    nodeL = list_get_next(&(a->B), nodeL);
}
```

Assume that `list_get_head` gets the pointer to head of list, and `list_get_next` gets the pointer to next element of passed second argument `elem`, of list.

Now my question is:

1. What is my loop condition here? Till what of list do I hope to loop? (see `I`) In other words, if `&(a->B)` is the address of the start of the list, what is `&a->B` here?

I thought this should loop till end of list, but it doesn't seem like that's what the while loop condition is doing. Also, this is a circular doubly linked list.

Comment: What is A in `&A->B` a `structure` or `some variable` defined before the code?

Comment: "->" has higher precedence than "&", so `&(A->B)` and `&A->B` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ShashankSingh I have modified my code - sorry for the mistake. Take a look now

Comment: @Sigismondo you sure? so both mean the same thing?

Comment: yes I am sure! that's just the pointer to the list in both cases. Just google around for "operator precedence", or test it in a test.c source... :)

Comment: The cast seems strange to me. How is list defined

Comment: @Sigismondo yes, thanks, so then looks like the loop wouldn't run in that case, since they will point to the same thing

Comment: I gave an answer, please see asap so if you need more explanation I can give it.

Comment: @4386427 the list definition is here in this question of mine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642853/interpreting-circular-doubly-linked-list-implementation-which-uses-union

Comment: It's head or tail depends on from where we start to run. In your scheme everything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elem* x = list_get_head(&a->B);
elem* y = (elem *)(&a->B);
```

First at all, how far do `x` and `y` differ in your case?

To be valid at all, first member of `list` must be of type `elem*` anyway. I personally would assume that this is the head of the list, but then your while loop won't ever be entered, so it must rather be the tail??? But then your first element considered in the loop is the tail...

How is an empty list represented? Null pointer? If so, this is not covered by your code.

```
while(nodeL != (elem *)(&a->B))
```

> did not get this part

Idea is simple: we start iterating at the head, and as long as the head is not reached *again*, we are still in the loop... Problem is, though, you have to distinguish two situations:

1. current node is head at start of the loop
2. current node is head after all elements have been iterated

I recommend different handling for iterating now:

```
elem* nodeL = list_get_head(&a->B);
if(nodeL) // based on assumption(!): otherwise, empty list
{
    do
    {
        //some code here
        nodeL = list_get_next(&a->B, nodeL);
    }
    while(nodeL != list_get_head(&a->B));
}
```

One element is guaranteed to be in the list, so we can use it unconditionally (thus a do-while loop). Then we iterate to the next element, until we reach the beginning again. I replaced the suspicious cast by another call to `list_get_head`, making the whole matter safer (not relying on assumptions any more either).

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct, thank you, I just realized too that I had to handle it this way. thanks for the code

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a `variable` and a `pointer` of the `structure`:

```
A var;
A* pntr;
```

Now to access a data member of the `structure` we do the following :

```
var.B    // For a variable use dot 
(*pntr).B or pntr->B    //For a pointer we can use * . or ->
```

In your code `while(nodeL != (elem *)(&a->B))`  iterates over the list till the head of the circular list is encountered again.

We can get head by :

```
A* a;
//SOME INITIAL CODE
A* pntr;
pntr = a;
head = (elem*)&(pntr->B)
```

So look at the look like:

```
while( nodeL != (elem *) ( & ( a->B ) ) )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but then, my loop wouldn't run in this case correct? because, initially, they are equal

Comment: Yep it wont run as they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you are talking about `std::list`. But since you are mentioning unfamiliar `list_get_head` and `list_get_next`, I assume this is a non standard implementation.

So the guess is: In a list head is also an element. The condition `while(nodeL != (elem *)(&A->B))` looks like it is checking when loop traverses back to the head of the circular list.

However, there are two observations:

1. Elements of a list are generally allocated from heap or a memory pool. Hence, if `B` is head, it should have been a pointer. Unless it is `typedef elem * list`.
2. The loop may not run because `nodeL` is already at head.

Comment: There is no std::list in C... Apart from, std::list is not circular either (not necessarily, at least).

Comment: thank you, yes, it does look like my loop wouldn't run in this case

Comment: and no, this is not std::list

Comment: I only mentioned std::list because of the name.